# How to save a 2-Dimensional array to a file in Java?

Tags: java, matrix, text-files

I have to add a matrix of a sudoku to a text-file, I have this code that allows me to save strings, I need to adapt it to save a two-dimensional array (matrix).

How can I adapt my code so it can save a matrix?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SudokuProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter textfile
               = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("path\\test.txt"));
            textfile.write("Hello");
            textfile.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SudokuProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SudokuProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] sudokuNumbers = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        try (
                PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sudokuNumbers.length; i++) {
                String s= "";
                for (int j = 0; j < sudokuNumbers[i].length; j++) {
                    s+= "|" + sudokuNumbers[i][j] + "|";
                }
                output.println(s);
            }
            output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It will generates this file structure:

[image]